# Error al mostrar datos JSON en recyclerview con Volley (JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject)

Tags: android-studio, android-volley, jsonobject, jsonarray

Tengo un webservice que devuelve un array Json el cual necesito listar en un recyclerview que tengo en un Fragment, pero me muestra el error: JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
JSON:

```html
 [{"Codigo":"00132",
  "Nombre":"Fabian Gonzalez",
  "Fecha_ingreso":"\/Date(1572106838607-0500)\/",
  "Id":34,
  "Telefono":"1234567890",
  "Ubicacion":"MEXICO"},
 {"Codigo":"00171",
  "Nombre":"Luis Yepez",
  "Fecha_ingreso":"\/Date(1572106838607-0500)\/",
  "Id":33,
  "Telefono":"56576565",
  "Ubicacion":"MEXICO"},
  etc...]
```

My Model

```html
public class MyModel {
    private int Id;
    public String Codigo;
    private String Nombre;
    public String Fecha_ingreso;
    private String Telefono;
    private String Ubicacion;

    public MyModel(){

    }

    public MyModel(int id, String Codigo, String Nombre, String Fecha_ingreso, String Telefono, String Ubicacion)
    {   
    Id = id;
        Codigo = Codigo;
        Nombre = Nombre;
        Fecha_ingreso = Fecha_ingreso;
        Telefono = Telefono;
        Ubicacion = Ubicacion;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        Id = id;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return Nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String Nombre) {
        Nombre = Nombre;
    }

    public String getFecha_ingreso() {
        return Fecha_ingreso;
    }

    public void setFecha_ingreso(String Fecha_ingreso) {
        Fecha_ingreso = Fecha_ingreso;
    }   

    public String getTelefono() {
        return Telefono;
    }

    public void setTelefono(String telefono) {
        Telefono = telefono;
    }
    
    public String getUbicacion() {
        return Ubicacion;
    }

    public void setUbicacion(String ubicacion) {
        Ubicacion = ubicacion;
    }
}
```

MyFragment

```html
public class Inicio extends Fragment implements Response.Listener<JSONObject>,Response.ErrorListener{
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    ArrayList<MyModel> lista;
    RequestQueue request;
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest;
    DataAdapter dataAdapter;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull  LayoutInflater inflater, @NonNull ViewGroup container, @NonNull Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View rootView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inicio, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_m);
        layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        lista=new ArrayList<>();

        request= Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
        mostrar_lista();

        return rootView;
    }

    private void mostrar_lista()
    {
      String url="http://www.mysite.mx/xxxxx/yyyyyy.svc/GetAll/"+156+"/"+"P"+"/"+1+"";
            url=url.replace(" ", "%20");
            jsonObjectRequest=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,this,this);
            request.add(jsonObjectRequest);           
    }

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"ERROR "+error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        System.out.println();
        Log.d("ERROR ",error.toString());      
    }

  @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        MyModel model=null;
        String obj = String.valueOf(response);
        JSONArray json=response.optJSONArray(obj);

        if (json != null)
        {
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
                    model = new MyModel();

                    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                    jsonObject = json.getJSONObject(i);

                    model.setId(jsonObject.optInt("Id"));
                    model.setCodigo(jsonObject.optString("Codigo"));
                    model.setNombre(jsonObject.optInt("Nombre"));
                    model.setFecha_ingreso(jsonObject.optString("Fecha_ingreso"));
                    model.setUbicacion(jsonObject.optString("Ubicacion"));
                    model.setTelefono(jsonObject.optString("Telefono"));                    
                    lista.add(model);
                }
                dataAdapter= new DataAdapter(lista);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
            }
            catch (JSONException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Error: "+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"No se encontraron datos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

My adapter

```html
public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.DataHolder>
{
    List<MyModel> lista;

    public DataAdapter(List<MyModel> lista)
    {
        this.lista=lista;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public DataHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
     View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.items_inicio,parent,false);       
        RecyclerView.LayoutParams layoutParams= new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        return new DataHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull DataHolder holder, int position) {
      holder.text_nombre.setText(lista.get(position).getNombre().toString());
        holder.txt_fecha.setText(lista.get(position).getFecha_ingreso().toString());
        holder.txt_tel.setText(lista.get(position).getTelefono().toString());
        holder.txt_ubicacion.setText((CharSequence) lista.get(position).getUbicacion().toString());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (lista != null)
        {
            return lista.size();
        }
      return 0;
    }

    public static class DataHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        TextView text_nombre,txt_fecha,txt_tel,txt_ubicacion;

        public DataHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            text_nombre=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nombre);
            txt_fecha=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.fecha);
            txt_tel=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.telefono);
            txt_ubicacion=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Ubicacion);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error es muy claro. El WS te devuelve un `JSONArray`, no un `JSONObject`. JSON es muy simple: si empieza por `[` es un `JSONArray`, si empieza por `{` es un `JSONObject`.

Eso significa que tu petición debe ser del tipo que te devuelve el WS. Además, se nota un movimiento que no tendría sentido, que sería convertir el `JSONArray` en `String`, cuando ya declaraste la respuesta de Volley del tipo que te devolvería el WS.

Sabiendo eso, necesitas adaptar varias cosas en tu código. Te pongo una versión con todos los cambios comentarios dentro. Si no funciona puedes decir en comentarios que errores tienes.

```
/*
    El Listener tiene que ser 
    del tipo de la respuesta: JSONArray
*/
public class Inicio extends Fragment implements Response.Listener<JSONArray>,Response.ErrorListener{
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    ArrayList<MyModel> lista;
    RequestQueue request;
    /*
        El tipo de request tiene también que ser 
        del tipo JsonArrayRequest
    */
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest;
    DataAdapter dataAdapter;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull  LayoutInflater inflater, @NonNull ViewGroup container, @NonNull Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View rootView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inicio, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_m);
        layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        lista=new ArrayList<>();

        request= Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
        mostrar_lista();

        return rootView;
    }

    private void mostrar_lista()
    {
      String url="http://www.mysite.mx/xxxxx/yyyyyy.svc/GetAll/"+156+"/"+"P"+"/"+1+"";
            url=url.replace(" ", "%20");
            jsonArrayRequest=new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,this,this);
            request.add(jsonArrayRequest);           
    }

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"ERROR "+error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        System.out.println();
        Log.d("ERROR ",error.toString());      
    }

  /*
     En el onResponse se declara también definido antes 
     que para este caso: JSONArray.
     Podría ser también JSONObject o String 
     si el WS devolviese eso en cuyo caso debes declarar
     todo el tipo coherente
  */

  @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
        MyModel model=null;

        /* 
           Esto no sería necesario ...
           String obj = String.valueOf(response);
           JSONArray json=response.optJSONArray(obj);

        */
        /* 
            Usar directamente response, pues es un JSONArray 
            En cuanto al if (json != null), conviene controlar
            desde el WS para mandar alguna clave de error cuando no haya datos
            ya los errores propios de red, etc son controlados desde
            el onError de Volley. 
            Lo dejo como lo tienes porque no conozco el contexto 
            ni sé si tienes potestad de cambiar el WS
        */
          if (json != null)
          {

            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    model = new MyModel();

                    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                    jsonObject = json.getJSONObject(i);

                    model.setId(jsonObject.optInt("Id"));
                    model.setCodigo(jsonObject.optString("Codigo"));
                    model.setNombre(jsonObject.optInt("Nombre"));
                    model.setFecha_ingreso(jsonObject.optString("Fecha_ingreso"));
                    model.setUbicacion(jsonObject.optString("Ubicacion"));
                    model.setTelefono(jsonObject.optString("Telefono"));                    
                    lista.add(model);
                }
                dataAdapter= new DataAdapter(lista);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
            }
            catch (JSONException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Error: "+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"No se encontraron datos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Supongo que tu WS devuelve **realmente** la respuesta como JSON. Si la devuelve como cadena entonces la petición de Volley debería ser del tipo `String` y hacer luego la conversión de esa cadena a un `JSONArray`.